# add images to wiki articles

Tags: mediawiki

I need to create a table with all the images and a button that says ADD, for the user to add the image to their page. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in functionality to do this, but you can link users to the **Special:NewImages** page so that they can see which images are available.

It is as simple as putting `[[File:Example.jpg]]` to insert an image, so with a quick explanation or help page I'm sure your users can figure out how to add the image to their page. The [Help:Images](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aImages) page is a good resource.

You could also write an extension to do this, but it would likely be a lot of work.

Comment: Thanks. How do I write a function for the image to go directly into the article without the user typing anything? @adrian archer